# RSpec: provide log level from command line

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I learned `logging` from this tutorial https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-ruby-logging/

I have added below function in `spec_helper.rb`

```
def logger(message)
  logger = Logger.new File.new('example.log', 'w')
  logger.info message
end
```

**high-level rspec sample_spec.rb**

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe 'test_feature' do
  it 'test_case_1' do
    expect(20).to be > 19
    logger.info '*********** Test Passed ***************'
  end

  it 'test_case_2' do
    expect(21).to be < 19
    logger.error '*********** Test Failed ***************'
  end
end
```

it generates `example.log` with error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `info' for 1:Integer
```

but I want logs both in the file and in console with the flexibility to define log levels at the command line.

How can I do that?
Here is minimal reproducible example https://github.com/jeevan1987cool/sample-rspec-logging

Comment: I cannot reproduce the failure - there is something missing from your post.  We have to assume that the Logger class is being manipulated elsewhere, such as in an initializer or other config file besides spec_helper.  When I define the same method and use it, it correctly writes to the example.log file.

Comment: I have not created a logger class. I have just added this function at the end of `spec_helped.rb`

Comment: It is still reproducible. I have created a minimal reproducible example here https://github.com/jeevan1987cool/sample-rspec-logging

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for making the example project. That helped. Did you notice that the `logger` method you defined in your repo is different from the `logger` method that you defined in your question?

From your question:

```
def logger(message)
  logger = Logger.new File.new('example.log', 'w')
  logger.info message
end
```

From your repo:

```
def logger
  logger = Logger.new File.new('example.log', 'w')
  logger.level = Logger::INFO
end
```

Assuming you meant to use the method definition from your repo (since the method from your question generates `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`) , the issue is that the last line of the method is:

```
logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

This call returns `1`, and since it's the last line in the method that becomes the default return value of the method.

You probably intended to return the `logger` object like this:

```
def logger
  logger = Logger.new File.new('example.log', 'w')
  logger.level = Logger::INFO
  logger
end
```

This will return something like this:

```
=> #<Logger:0x00007ffe0a32b300
 @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007ffe0a32a888 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @formatter=nil,
 @level=1,
 @logdev=
  #<Logger::LogDevice:0x00007ffe0a32a130
   @dev=#<File:example.log>,
   @filename=nil,
   @mon_count=0,
   @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007ffe0a329b90>,
   @mon_mutex_owner_object_id=70364534755480,
   @mon_owner=nil,
   @shift_age=nil,
   @shift_period_suffix=nil,
   @shift_size=nil>,
 @progname=nil>
```

It will also successfully log information to `example.log`.

All that said, it probably will not function the way you expect: every call to `logger` reinitializes the object by calling `Logger.new File.new('example.log', 'w')`, and calling `File.new` in the `w` mode will overwrite any existing file. Therefore, calling `logger` twice means you will write `example.log` then overwrite its contents again. You can read more about [IO Open Modes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) in the Ruby docs. So the first thing you'll want to do is fix your open mode.

The next thing you'll want to do is find a way to memoize this value so it doesn't get reinitialized over and over again. That's outside the scope of your question and this answer, and given the discrepancy between your question and your repo I'd prefer not to try fixing something you haven't explicitly described in your original question. Good luck!

Comment: It worked, IO Open modes also helped. But how to have logs both in logs and in the file? and a parameter to pass in the command line to turn on/off debug/info/error logs?

Comment: Use environment variables to control it from the command line.

Comment: Could you please share a working snippet? Also, I have tried different IO Open modes like `w`, `w+`, `a`,`a+` but none of them suited my requirement. It either keeps on appending on the same file or create new for every `it` under `describe`. E.g if there are 10 `it` under a `describe` then log file will refresh 10 times.

Comment: I have made some changes in the same repo, in order to get both log file and logs printed in the terminal. But it only creates a file and does not print anything in console. Please check.